# Testing an action creator that dispatches multiple action creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have this action creator I am attempting to test:

```
export const fetchAllItems = (topicIds)=>{
  return (dispatch)=>{
    topicIds.forEach((topicId, index, array)=>{
      const last = index+1 == array.length;
      dispatch(fetchItems(topicId, last));
    });
  };
};
```

I'd like to assert that `fetchItems` has been called twice - first with `1, false` and second with `2, true`. I've tried `redux-mock-store`, but not sure I'm using it right:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore();
store.dispatch(fetchAllItems([1, 2])).then(()=>{       
  console.log(store.getActions()); //Throws error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
});
```

I've also tried mocking `dispatch` and `fetchItems` but can't seem to get that working either.

Comment: would you need to return a `Promise` in the returned function by `fetchAllItems`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a mock store, I usually just use a [spy](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/spies/) to capture the dispatched actions

```
let dispatch = sinon.spy()
fetchAllItems([1, 2, 3])(dispatch)
expect(dispatch).to.have.been.calledWithMatch({ type: "...", ... })
```

This does get harder if the thunk does not dispatch the action directly, but you can use the spy to get the thunk and repeat the process until standard actions are dispatched

```
let dispatch = sinon.spy()
fetchAllItems([1, 2, 3])(dispatch)
let fetchItems = dispatch.getCall(0).args[0]
fetchItems(dispatch)
expect(dispatch).to.have.been.calledWithMatch({ type: "...", ... })
```

Comment: Note: the assertions used in my examples make use of [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your calling `.then`, but your action creator does not return a Promise (which you don't have to unless you need it). You can change your tests to:

```
store.dispatch(fetchAllItems([1, 2]));
console.log(store.getActions());
```

Comment: The result of that `console.log` is `[]`. I'm thinking the problem is that `fetchItems` is not an action.

Comment: @AndrewSamuelsen yeah, I assumed `fetchItems` was an action since you're doing a dispatch on it.